# Why "Tap to copy the URL for this app" notification appears for my PWA every time I open it

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA in React. May I know what is causing this notification "Tap to copy the URL for this app." to appear in notification center every time i open the app? Below is my manifest.json:

```js
{
  "name": "System Name",
  "short_name": "System",
  "icons": [
    { ...
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/bwc/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#0066FF",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

[Screenshot of "Tap to copy the url for this app" notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eG4j.jpg)

Comment: It's an automatic chrome notification for PWAs. Shown since for an installed PWA the user does not see the URL. They are trying to be helpful to the user. You should be able to hide that by clicking on the notification settings link shown there.

Comment: I've the same issue here. My PWA doesn't look "full screen" because this notification is showing... Any lucky how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior in Chrome, and there's no way to disable it at the current time.

You can star [Chromium bug 1066658](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1066658) to add your support to the ability to disable the notification. If you have specific use cases, or user journeys that would be affected by removing this, add those as a comment.